# Window resize function not firing. Just to make sure it still does said function inside if resized less than and then above

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sticky

I've just been working on a sticky nav when screen is scrolled below 550px.
I've got the function working but when window is resized to below 992px it's meant to stop being sticky then if again resized above it should work but if I go back to below 992px it stays sticky so I believe the resize isn't working. See code below:

```
    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {

    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var y = $(document).scrollTop(), //get page y value
            header = $(".menu-faq-nav-container");
        if (y >= 550) {
            header.css({position: "fixed", top: "0", right: "50px"});
        } else {
            header.css({position: "relative", right: "0"});
        }
    });
} else {}

$(window).resize(function () {

    if ($(window).width() >= 992) {

        $(document).scroll(function () {
            var y = $(document).scrollTop(), //get page y value
                header = $(".menu-faq-nav-container");
            if (y >= 550) {
                header.css({position: "fixed", top: "0", right: "50px"});
            } else {
                header.css({position: "relative", right: "0"});
            }
        });
    } else {}
});
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Your logic is creating duplicate scroll event handlers.  Every time you resize the window and the width is >= 992 it creates a new one.  Doing so does not remove previous ones.  **Do not duplicate bind event handlers**

Comment: Do your width check inside your scroll handler, and then you only have to bind the scroll handler once, and you don't have to care about the resize at all.  If they go below the width, the scroll will do nothing.  Once they go equal to or above, it will start processing as you desire.

Comment: Duhh, wow, can't believe I even thought of doing it the other way. Just solved a lot for me. Daft me :') Fancy adding this as an answer so I can make as answered. Perfect though thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main concern with this question is the duplicate event bindings.  You are creating a new scroll event binding every time the resize happens, provided the width is larger than your desired minimum value.  This means each scroll event it going to be processed multiple times, in an identical manner.  Which means you're doing too much work, and can lead to issues.

Also, once you fall below your minimum desired width, those scroll events do not go away.  They still exist.  So in order to removed the duplicate scroll event bindings, and to solve the issue of the scroll event handler processing when it should not, you should consider binding the scroll event handler once, and check the window width inside it.  A which point you do not care about the resize event.  The width is either above your minimum width or it is not.

Comment: Once again, Thank you so much. Explained alot!

Comment: Hi Taplar, Just wanted to check, When you say I don't need the resize event. I've just taken a look, this is the start of my code         $(document).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
            var y = $(document).scrollTop()                                 But when I have scrolled and then resized it still keeps the fixed position. Would you say that I actually need to take into consideration people resizing their browsers or would you say it's not worth the hassle?

Comment: Ah, true.  In that case try changing `$(document).scroll(function` to `$(document).on('scroll resize', function`